# Google Apps Script to send different auto-replies based on keyword in email body

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Basically I am trying to setup different auto-replies based on the content of the email body. Below is my current code... In this case, I am trying to set it up so that if an email was sent with the body "test" it will auto-reply with "This is my test". But if it's anything else it will say "Sorry, your keyword was not recognized". Preferably would like to add more than one keyword in the future...

However, no matter what I send, it is only auto-replying with "This is my test"....

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

```
function autoReplier() 
{var labelObj = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('autoreply');
var gmailThreads;
var messages;
var sender;for (var gg = 0; gg < labelObj.getUnreadCount(); gg++) {
gmailThreads = labelObj.getThreads()[gg];
messages = gmailThreads.getMessages();
for (var ii = 0; ii < messages.length; ii++) 
  {if (messages[ii].isUnread()){msg = messages[ii].getPlainBody();
    if (msg = "test") {
        sender = messages[ii].getFrom();MailApp.sendEmail(sender, "Auto Reply", "This is my test");                                                                     
        messages[ii].markRead();
        messages[ii].moveToTrash();
    } else {
        sender = messages[ii].getFrom();MailApp.sendEmail(sender, "Auto Reply", "Sorry, your keyword was not 
recognized");                                                                         
        messages[ii].markRead();
        messages[ii].moveToTrash();
}
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Change `if(msg = "test")` to `if(msg == "test")`

Comment: Hmm, after making this change I am only getting the "Sorry, your keyword was not recognized" message

Comment: You can print the content of the variable `msg`. Put `Logger.log(msg)`  after `msg = messages[ii].getPlainBody()` and then go to views => log to see the content of `msg`. It has to be exactly `test` to be a match. No spaces, no upper case letters etc. If you want to just match "test" regardless of the surrounding content do `if(msg.includes("test")`. Also it is a good practice to separate your different code blocks into separate lines. While this is not the issue here, it makes your code unreadable and also difficult to debug. Just a recommendation.

Comment: I see... thank you! This worked. There was a lot more content in the email than I thought. Is there a way for me to say if "test" is between "this" and "that"? In my case "this" and "that" are always going to be the same

Comment: Are `this` `test` and `that` consecutive words? Like : `"this test that"` ? Or they have other words in between ?

Comment: Yes they are consecutive. Although they are on their own lines. So line one is this, line two is test and line three is that

Comment: Did you print the `msg` at least for one iteration? you say different lines but how does it look like? if they are consecutive try this: `if(msg.includes("this test that")` . But most likely you need `if(msg.includes("this\ntest\n\that")` but please post your string otherwise we don't know what the structure is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225267/discussion-between-scott-neustadt-and-marios).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation / Issues:

You have one obvious issue with your code and one additional modification you need to do according to your comments:

- Replace `if(msg = "test")` with `if(msg == "test")` otherwise the first `if` block statement will be always executed.
- According to your comments `msg` is not just a single word but a text. And you want to **check** if `test` is between two words. Assuming that these words are `this` and `that` you can use the following regular expression to see if `test` is between `this` and `that`:

  ```
  const regex = RegExp(/(?<=this.*?)test(?=.*?that)/);
  regex.test(msg) // this returns true if test is between this and that
  ```

The [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method allows you to validate your regular expression and get `true` if there is a match between the regular expression and a specified string, in your case `msg`.

### Solution:

```
function autoReplier() 
{var labelObj = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('autoreply');
var gmailThreads;
var messages;
const regex = RegExp(/(?<=this.*?)test(?=.*?that)/); //modify this and that if you want to use other words
var sender;
for (var gg = 0; gg < labelObj.getUnreadCount(); gg++) {
gmailThreads = labelObj.getThreads()[gg];
messages = gmailThreads.getMessages();
for (var ii = 0; ii < messages.length; ii++) 
  {if (messages[ii].isUnread()){msg = messages[ii].getPlainBody();
    if (regex.test(msg)) {
        sender = messages[ii].getFrom();
        MailApp.sendEmail(sender, "Auto Reply", "This is my test");                                                                     
        messages[ii].markRead();
        messages[ii].moveToTrash();
    } else {
        sender = messages[ii].getFrom();
        MailApp.sendEmail(sender, "Auto Reply", "Sorry, your keyword was not recognized");                                                                         
        messages[ii].markRead();
        messages[ii].moveToTrash();
}}}}
}
```